# Error upgrading from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4.3, magento2.4.4

After changing the version from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, I'm getting the following error when trying to execute "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" or "php bin/magento setup:di:compile":

> In ClassReader.php line 34:
> Class Df\Framework\Logger\Handler does not exist

[image]

Any idea what causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are installed Mage2Pro module(s) on your site and their modules does not compatible, so you should disable/remove these modules to upgrade to magento 2.4.4

After that, run the following commands:

```
rm -rf vendor
composer install
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I uninstalled that module, but the error message remains.

This error message persists even after removing all third party modules.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please give it a try.

Comment: Tried the commands, but still got the same error.

Comment: Could you confirm that you are installed M2ePro modules? How do you uninstall these modules?

Comment: I uninstalled the M2E Pro module with the command "composer removem2epro/magento2-extension"

Comment: Compare you `lib` folder with the magento core (codebase) https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.4/lib I guess maybe M2EPro modules put their files in `lib` folder. Then remove any folders/files related to M2EPro modules. Then re-run the commands I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Started all over again and after uninstalling Mage2Pro the upgrade went fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

> Run the below command and check if you got any files;

```
grep -r "Df.Framework.Logger.Handler" app/
grep -r "Df.Framework.Logger.Handler" vendor/
```

> If file found then fixed it's namespace otherwise remove **var/**, **vendor/** and **generated/** folder using **rm -rf**  command and run below commands

```
composer install
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I get no results when useing the grep commands

Comment: Okay, so I think you need to check are your on right folder location?